# Use setType() on intent to allow only jpeg and png images; not gif images

Tags: android, image, android-intent, jpeg, mime-types

I'm developing an Android app where a user has to select an image from the gallery. This image should have either .jpeg/.png extension.

I have tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
i.setType("image/jpeg, image/png");
```

However, it still allows me to select .gif images. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely, since that is not a valid MIME type, it fails to parse and is ignored. [`setType()` is not documented to support multiple MIME types](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType(java.lang.String)). On Android 4.4+, you can [use `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES), but only with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. Also note that `ACTION_PICK` will not necessarily bring up any form of "gallery" app.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay, but is there any alternate way for preventing a gif file from being selected?

Comment: On Android 4.4+, try using `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES` to limit you to the two MIME types you want. On older devices, only ask for one MIME type, and if needed, give the user separate menu (or whatever) options for PNG or JPEG. Or, do not worry about the MIME type, and if the user chooses a GIF, convert it to a PNG yourself.

Comment: Okay :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Your code should look like this, if you want to specify the image formats that you want to allow:

```
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
final Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            .setType("image/*")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
```

Comment: Calling setType after setting URI in Intent constructor will clear the data. Call setDataAndType instead.